# I want to hide the button in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a HTML form code is as follows

```
   <div id="foo" style="display:none;">
   <input type="text" name="name">
   <input type="text" name="name1">
   <input type="text" name="name2">
   </div>
   <input type="button" onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');" 
   value="Add more" />
```

Upon clicking add more all the above textboxes, but the button is still visible and i want to hide that button

Following is the javascript

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
```

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why don't you use `.toggle()`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
function toggle_visibility(btn,id) {
       //hide button
       btn.style.display = 'none';
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
```

```html
<div id="foo" style="display:none;">
   <input type="text" name="name">
   <input type="text" name="name1">
   <input type="text" name="name2">
</div>
   <input type="button" onclick="toggle_visibility(this,'foo');" 
   value="Add more" />
```

Try this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this : Use `this` object to get button and change its display property.

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
       //hide button
       this.style.display = 'none';
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
```

OR - keep button inside foo `div` and your code will work as it is

```
<div id="foo" style="display:none;">
   <input type="text" name="name">
   <input type="text" name="name1">
   <input type="text" name="name2">

   <input type="button" onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');" 
   value="Add more" /> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You tagged the question with `jQuery`, so why not use it?

```js
$("input[type=button]").click(function() {
    $("#foo").show();
    $(this).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="foo" style="display:none;">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="text" name="name1">
  <input type="text" name="name2">
</div>

<input type="button" value="Add more" />
```

Comment: My code is already working. when i click add more it opens 3 text fields.i want to hide the button addmore when the fields are visible. in other words, after the click the button it should show the fields and the button must be hidden

Comment: Edited my answer. Is this what you mean? @ShebasKhan

Answer (score -1):

**Give id to your  tag**

```
<button type="button" id='btnclick'>Add More</button>
```

**use below jquery**

```
$("#btnclick").click(function(){

    $("#btnclick").hide();
}
});
```